# How to set Encoding to Http Post request android

Tags: android, character-encoding, http-headers

How can i set the `UTF` encoding to `Http Post` request?

Here is my code snippet.

```
HttpClient httpClient = getNewHttpClient();

    String user_agent = (String) httpClient.getParams().getParameter(
            CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT)
            + " Android";
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
            user_agent);
    httpClient.getParams().setBooleanParameter(
            "http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(remoteUrl);
    System.out.println("Url:" + remoteUrl + "  values:"
            + nameValuePair.toString());
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));


    response = httpClient.execute(post);
    int postStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println("result:" + result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may set any header by calling 
`post.setHeader("HEADER NAME","HEADER VALUE");`

In your case it should be

`post.setHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");`

Comment: It worked with this  

request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));